# How can i create dynamicly html table with Angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have an array that has got 100 item inside it. I want to render this array in my html page as html table 10x10 (10 tr and each tr has 10 td). How can i do it in angular ?

```
  tableIndexTR = [];
  tableIndexTD = [];

  constructor(private data: TransferService) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    for (let _i = 1; _i <= 10; _i++) {
        this.tableIndexTR.push(_i);
    }

    for (let _j = 1; _j <= 10; _j++) {
        this.tableIndexTD.push(_j);
      }
  }


  <table style="width: 100%">
      <tr *ngFor="let item of tableIndexTR">
          <td *ngFor="let item of tableIndexTD">{{item}}</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @dince12 i updated the question and added what i have tried. I m sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.tableIndex = [];

for (let _i = 0; _i < 10; _i++) {
    let tmp = [];

    for (let _j = 1; _j <= 10; _j++) {
        tmp.push(_i * 10 + _j);
      }

        this.tableIndex.push({
           subArray: tmp
        });
   }


   <div *ngFor=“let row of tableIndex”>
           <div *ngFor=“let col of row.subArray”>
                   {{col}}
           </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Firstly thank you so much for your answer. But i could not understand how i will i use 'this.tableIndex[i][j]' this part in html side.

Comment: That makes sense?

Comment: Ah i think this code is not what i am looking for. Actually i dont need 2 array. Just one array is enough for me that has number 1 to 100. My problem is i want to  render this array this way : 

1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10
11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19-20

first line 1-10 secon line 11-20 ect ..

I hope this time i could explain my point :) @user1779362

Comment: Ok changed answer to give you that